# PSpice Thyristor DC Switch

Tags: dc, pspice, thyristor

So I am trying to model a thyristor switching circuit but the results I get are as if the SCR that is used as a switch lets the current go through even though the gate current hasn't been applied yet.

I've also observed that the switch for the gate current doesn't really work. Is that the reason of the problem? How can I fix this?

This is the circuit design on ORCAD Capture and simulation settings:
[image]
This is the current/time graph of R5 and R6:
[image]
This is the current/time graph of R6 (zoomed in) which shows me that the switch doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: Gate leakage current needs to be bled off with a shunt resistor.  try 10k to gnd.

Answer (score 3):

The current source in your simulation is ideal.  That means it doesn't care if the switch is open or closed.  It will produce very high voltages to make the 100A flow through the gate even if the switch is open.  Best bet is to replace it with a voltage source.  100A is way to much gate current.  Try replacing I1 with a 5V source and making R6 1k.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. However, it now seems the thyristor blocks the current even after the gate current gets applied. I looked at the datasheet for the thyristor and I think the parameters for the R6 and voltage source should trigger the thyristor but it seems it is not getting triggered? Now, the current/time graph for R5 looks like this: s29.postimg.org/rlxc3upnb/image.png

Comment: Look at the voltage on the gate.  It should be 0 before the switch is closed and go to something like 0.7-1V when closed  If it is not zero before the switch is closed add a resistor from the gate to ground.  It can be pretty big.